# ERROR: Error [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7' while executing command python setup.py egg_info

Tags: python, pip

I got some trouble with pip.

I recently try to install some packages and sometimes (not all the time), i get an error which i'm still not able to correct.

I already check many anwsers on stackoverflow and github. However, nothing seems to work.
I will be interested to get your advices ont this.

For example with the package requests-html

```
louis@louis ~ % python3 -m pip install requests-html
Collecting requests-html
  Using cached requests_html-0.10.0-py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
Collecting parse
  Downloading parse-1.19.0.tar.gz (30 kB)
  ERROR: Error [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7' while executing command python setup.py egg_info
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7'
```

```
louis@Louis ~ % python3 --version
Python 3.10.6
```

I'm on MacOs and i already upgraded pip to latest version.

Thank's everyone

---

Update
I aslo check the folder bin at /usr/local/opt/python/bin/

and i seem to have a folder named python3.7

```
louis@Louis python % cd bin
louis@Louis bin % ls
2to3            idle3.10        pydoc3          python3-config      python3.7
2to3-3.10       pip3            pydoc3.10       python3.10      wheel3
idle3           pip3.10         python3         python3.10-config   wheel3.10
```

while trying to update with python3.10

```
louis@Louis ~ % python3.10 -m pip install requests-html
Collecting requests-html
  Using cached requests_html-0.10.0-py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
Collecting w3lib
  Downloading w3lib-2.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (21 kB)
Collecting pyppeteer>=0.0.14
  Using cached pyppeteer-1.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (83 kB)
Collecting pyquery
  Using cached pyquery-1.4.3-py3-none-any.whl (22 kB)
Collecting bs4
  Using cached bs4-0.0.1.tar.gz (1.1 kB)
  ERROR: Error [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7' while executing command python setup.py egg_info
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your default Python version seems to be 3.7, that's where pip is trying to install it, based on this part:

```
No such file or directory: '/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7'
```

Did you uninstall Python 3.7 after installing Python 3.10?

You either should

```
python3.10 -m pip install requests-html
```

or make Python 3.10 as your default:
https://dev.to/malwarebo/how-to-set-python3-as-a-default-python-version-on-mac-4jjf

Comment: Hi tocy, thank's for the answer, i tried  you python3.1 intall , but still get 'No such file or directory: '/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7' '...

Comment: And to answer your question, no i didn't uninstall python 3.7 after upgrading python to 3.10

Comment: Hmmmm, that is weird, which folder do you have in your PATH variable? https://www.educative.io/answers/how-to-add-python-to-the-path-variable-in-mac
Maybe it is still pointing to the 3.7 version.

If all else fails, uninstall both and install Python 3.10 and make sure when you install tick in the add to PATH variable checkbox

Comment: tocy thank you for the answer, in my /etc/paths i only have folders leading to : /usr/local/bin , /usr/bin , /bin , /usr/sbin, /sbin

Comment: Edit : I added the path : '/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7' to /etc/paths but still getting the same error (i also try to add path to python3.10 folder, same results)

Answer (score 0):

I had something very similar happen to my own install. I think it happened because I had previously installed with a download from the Python website but later switched to using a `brew install` version.

What fixed it for me was to explicitly uninstall and then re-instal with `brew`:

```bash
brew uninstall python@3.7
brew install python@3.7
```